# jQuery .delay() timing issue, not all the animations have a consistant delay?

Tags: jquery, animation, delay, timing

I have a simle bit of jQuery code which hides a group of gallery objects when the controls are clicked, and then shows the filtered objects one by one.

The issue is that some of the delays are inconsistent and not evenly timed. The delay increments every time an object begins to fadein to make them appear one by one, but one or two appear at the same time on random occurances?

Heres the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var controls = $('#portfolio-nav'); 
    var gallery = $('#gallery');

    $('a', controls).click(function(){

        /* setup variables */
        var nav             = $(this).closest('ul');
        var listItem        = $(this).parent();
        var current         = 'current';
        var classes         = listItem.attr("class").split(/\s/);
        var elementsToShow  = new Array();
        var allElements     = gallery.children();

        /* filter classes to excude .current */
        classes = jQuery.grep(classes, function(value){
            return value != current;
        });
        var sector = classes[classes.length -1];

        /* remove all .current classes */
        nav.children('.current').each(function() {    
            $(this).removeClass('current');
        });

        /* add the .current class to the clicked li */
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        /* define which elements to show */
        $(allElements).each(function() {

            var element = $(this);          
            var elementSectors = element.attr("class").split(/\s/);

            if(sector !== 'all'){

                if(jQuery.inArray(sector, elementSectors) !== -1){
                    elementsToShow.push(element);
                }

            } else {
                elementsToShow.push(element);
            }

        });

        /* log the elements */
        //console.log(elementsToShow);

        /* hide/show all the elements */
        animateThem(allElements, elementsToShow);

        /* clear the array for the next click */
        elementsToShow.length = 0;

        return false;
    });

    function animateThem(allElements, elementsToShow){

        $(allElements).fadeOut('fast').delay(200);

        $(elementsToShow).each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(100*index).fadeIn('normal');
        });

    }

});
```

Heres a quick snippet of the html:

```
<nav id="portfolio-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="all current"><a href="#all">All</a></li>
        <li class="branding"><a href="#branding">Branding</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="gallery">
    <div class="grid-3 media-holder branding">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3 media-holder marketing">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Its probably an easy fix as my jQuery isn't great, but if anyone knows of a reason why this would happen I'd love to know.

Cheers,

Dave

**Edit: Had issues with declaring the array elements and was getting an undeclared error...after some tweaking its working as expected (thanks to Dannie Hansen), JSFiddle is below if anyone is interested:**

http://jsfiddle.net/daveaspinall/8VKad/9/

Comment: In general I'd rather use a callback-approach instead of a calculated delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure, there could be some sort of timing issue.

Why don't you give it a try using interval:

```
var intCount = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if(typeof elementsToShow[intCount] != undefined) {
         if(elementsToShow[intCount] != "fired") {
              elementsToShow[intCount].fadeIn('normal');
              elementsToShow[intCount] = "fired";
              intCount++;
         }
    } else {
    //End of array, clear the interval
         clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 100);
```

That is how it could be done using an interval to time the events. Give it a try and report back if it worked :)

**Edit1** Edited to fix bug. - (Thanks to Brighty)

**Edit2** Fixed the fadeIn function. Give it a try now.

Comment: hi dannie, thanks for the quick reply! I'm getting an error "elementsToShow[intCount] is undefined"? Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you replace the current $.each with the new interval method. As far as i can see your array with elements comes with the parameters to the function. Which means if you use this outside the function it will give undefined errors.

Try to console log the elementsToShow and make sure it is indexed 0-999, also make sure that the 

"if(typeof elementsToShow[intCount] !== undefined) {"

Line is working properly, if not try to use the following:

"if(elementsToShow[intCount] != undefined) {"

Comment: yea i replaced the old .each() function with the one above inside the function. I'll keep looking see if its something obvious (usually is)

Comment: You must have the undefined part without quotes. It will not work otherwise. The reason for this is that we count our way up the array and when it hit a undefined index(Which means the array is over) it will terminate the interval. But try the other example of a undefined check and see if it work. Another thing you could do if this takes up too much of your time is to remove the delay method from your $.each and instead of 'normal' as the time you could just extend the time it takes for it to fadeIn. So it still has this trail event look :)

Comment: A few fixes have been made. Give the new example a try :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. the code is right but i logged the elementsToShow[intCount] and it was in face undefined so the check is working. so i then logged the array and this is what it contains: [jQuery(div.grid-3), jQuery(div.grid-3), jQuery(div.grid-3)]. How would I got about iterating through this? Sorry as you can tell my jQuery is quite limited!

Comment: i tried the edited code above but still get the error "elementsToShow[intCount] is undefined"? ive updated the question to include the function you wrote so you cans ee what I'm using. might just accept the delay issue :-/